# Layers will not hold specified CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, layers

I have several layers from OpenStreetMap that I wanted to convert to WGS 84 4326 due to my using several base layers that are assigned to that CRS.

No matter what I try, whenever I check the layer they all say "this layer does not have a specified CRS"

Things I have tried:

Set project to WGS 84 4326.Turned OTF on and off. 
Set CRS in layer options and saved it and reloaded it.
QGIS settings to prompt me when I add a layer missing a CRS which it does not prompt.

I have used a raster image to compare against my OSM layers and it would change accordingly to my projection change. Although it would never match the location of these OSM layers regardless of projection.

Comment: Is the OSM layer a web service, or data you've downloaded?

Comment: It is data I've downloaded from: http://download.geofabrik.de/ I downloaded all of the SHP files I needed directly from there.

Comment: I downloaded a few shapefiles from the same source, and have no problem. Could you specify which shapefile you're using? Also, have you tried the "Assign CRS" tool?

Comment: I have not tried that tool. Is it a plugin I can try? I downloaded all of the OSM SHP sets of Ontario and Quebec and NY state. Out of curiosity, with the layers loaded in QGIS, if you go to set layer CRS what does it say? I'd like to just compare what I see. Appreciate your help.

Comment: In QGIS 3, it's under the Vector General group in the processing toolbox. In QGIS 2.18, you could try using Define Current Projection under Vector > Data Management Tools. When I open the Set Layer CRS dialog, it just brings up the appropriate menu, and I am able to change it without issue. Perhaps add a screenshot of what you're getting.

Comment: Hey Josh, here is a link: [Raster and Polygon](https://imgur.com/a/QJodp) I have set layer CRS on both these files repeatedly and saved as WGS 4326. I just loaded them in QGIS and as you will see, the poly file still says no CRS is set. The raster does have it set however they are not lining up AT ALL. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: I also noticed that the extents don't match up. I'm not very well versed with Q so not sure how to change or even be sure whether their respective units of measurement as per their extents are the same.